# Can't make pyttsx speak the ';' symbol

Tags: python, pyttsx

I'm developing a code using pyttsx, and it's working great. But i'm having this small problem where I need it to speak the `;` and possibly other symbols in the future such as `.`

Is there any way that I can make it work, like any flag I need to pass to it or should I just be glad that it's reading all the rest I need?

I've tried to go through it's documentation but couldn't find nothing in it that could help me or answer my question wether is it possible or not.

Thanks a lot and stay awesome!

Comment: How do you expect `;` to be pronounced?

Comment: If it says "semicolon" to me is more than enough